# Bluestacks problem regarding Data Files

Tags: bluestacks

I once uninstalled bluestacks. But i had saved its game data. And then when reinstalling it i actually had to stop and close in just when it was about to end. Due to a power cut. So next time i opened my windows 7 pc i found bluestacks in my computer. I opened it and it took a hour or so to download game data but usually it should take 3 or so minute as of i know if we uninstall it while saving game data, the next time installation and game data and initializing doesn't take much of a time. But as it was taking so much time i did some copy paste work with the files in program data>bluestacks in my windows 7. And now instead of taking its own game data in program data its downloading the game data which takes a lot of my internet !

PC specs -
PC : AMD Athlon X2 250 3.00 ghz
OP : WIndows 7
Ram : 2 gb
system : 64 bit operating system

Details -
I've installed it before and have uninstalled it many times before as well and i know it  takes the old game data if i save them. But this time it isn't

My problem -

I want to ask what to do, i already have the data in program data>bluestacks which is about 3.34 gb. And if its downloading game data again will it download only the damaged or missing files ? or the whole game data ?

What to do ? how do i make the software accept its former game data ?